# Show master records when sub records are chosen in one form

Tags: ms-access-2016, subform

Tough to come up with a good title for this. I'm working on an HOA database in Access 2016.

There is a Members Table (MemberID PK) and Lots table (LotID_PK, MemberID_FK and LotNumber). It is possible for members to join lots to get a break on assessment fees.

So Mary Jones owns lots 0001, 0002, 0003 and wants to join them, I have it set up so that the end user enters the joined lot numbers into the Joined Lots subform (based on the Lots table) and the master lot number joins them (in this case 0001).

They show up fine when the master lot number is chosen in the Lots Form, but what I would like to happen is when lot number 0002 is chosen I would like 0001 and 0003 to show up in the Joined Lots subform.

I don't even know if this is possible but I'm looking for suggestions.

Comment: Sorry, Access 2016.

Comment: I'm curious, why was my post edited? Am I not allowed to say "thank you in advance"?